# Unable to access javascript variable from another file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble accessing a globally declared javascript variable that is declared in a separate file.
My code:

```
<script src="scripts/one.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/two.js"></script>
```

One.js:

```
var config = {
    form: 'form',
    validate: {
        '#first-name': {
            'validation': 'required',
            'error-msg': 'Required Field'
        },
        // other validation rules
    }
};
```

Two.js:

```
    $.validate({
    modules: 'jsconf',
    onModulesLoaded: function () {
        $.setupValidation(config);
    }
});
```

I receieve the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined
```

on load of the page. Any reason why this would be happening when I am including the scripts in the appropriate order?

Comment: are your paths to the files correct?

Comment: Are you sure it is actually loading? Network tab?

Comment: look under network in the console

Comment: Is the whole of the files? Or are they wrapped in an IIFE?

Comment: Yes, both files are available to the page when I inspect the document and both scripts are wrapped in the jQuery ready function.

Comment: @noclist if they're wrapped in the Jquery ready function, then they're only accessible to/in that function. Look at [JS scopes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Comment: @George that was my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.yourGlobalVariable
```

Use window.variable name to get variable between files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the variable is defined in a function. Either move it outside of the function or use `window.varName`

```js
var a = 1;

// File 1
$(function() {
  var b = 2;
  window.d = 4;
  console.log(a);
});

// File 2
$(function() {
  var c = 3;
  console.log(a);
  console.log(d);
  console.log(b); // This will throw an error because b is not defined in this scope
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I suggest you read about [JS scopes](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript) if you want to learn more.